# Drupal hook_menu wildcard on first argument

Tags: drupal, wildcard, hook-menu

I am looking to make a wildcard page on

```php
$items['%/pagename']
```

But I can't get it to work.
Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ist Parameter in url can not be made dynamic with %. you can repetitively include all possible values in place of %.

Comment: Perhaps I can use htaccess? Not sure how to do this though :(